# C# Получение TCP флагов соединения при запросе через WebRequest(HttpWebRequest)

Tags: c#, tcp

Доброго времени суток Коллеги!

Подскажите, или направьте в какую сторону "копать".

Я Клиент(https) при установке соединения с сервером хотел бы писать данные сокета, а именно TCP флаги:

- URG — указывает, что сегмент содержит срочные данные.
- ACK — указывает, что сегмент содержит номер подтверждения.
- PSH — указывает, что данные нужно протолкнуть к получающему пользователю.
- RST — сбрасывает соединение.
- SYN — используется для синхронизации порядковых номеров.
- FIN — указывает конец данных.

Возможно ли это сделать если подключение я создаю через WebRequest(HttpWebRequest)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https:\\mail.ru");
```

Быть может можно прикрутить какое-то событие в ServicePointManager для того чтобы слушать соединение.

Из предистории: намедни столкнулся с тем что создавая соединение с сервером кто-то из нас двоих(я или сервер) разрывал это соединение. При общении с администратором сервера мне порекомендовали поднять таймаут при установке соединения, но мои таймауты были более 120000 миллисекунд, а соединение рвалось на 3 секунде.

```
WebException: Базовое соединение закрыто: Соединение было неожиданно закрыто. (WebExceptionStatus: ConnectionClosed)
```

В результате двух дней разбора полетов я доказал что соединение рву не я, админ нашел чего-то там у себя и сказал что поднял таймаут, и всё успешно взлетело! Но прежде чем это все взлетело пришлось разбираться с wireshark. Сейчас для себя и повышения своей квалификации я пытаюсь разобраться и дополнить свой код отладочной информацией. (Готов выслушать любые Ваши рекомендации с чего начать разбор таких полетов, если есть пример кода получения данных TCP flags из WebRequest(HttpWebRequest) отдельное спасибо)

Comment: Вряд ли это можно сделать в .NET коде.